# Express probability of an event in terms of some variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Three people $A,B,C$ go to a shop and buy either pen or notebook. Three choices are mutually independent and each person buys pen with probability $p$. Let $X$ be the event that at least two of them buy pens and $Y$ be the event that $A$ buys pen. How, can we express probability of event $X$, that is, $P(X)$ in terms of $p$? Also, can we find conditional probabilities in terms of $p$?

My idea: Since each buys pen with probability $p$, we have $P(X) = 3p^{2}(1-p) + p^{3}$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That means $P(X|Y) = 2p^{2}(1-p)+p^{3}$ and similarly I can get other way.

Comment: Have you used the Bayes theorem?

Comment: No, I directly find $P(X \cap Y)$ and $P(Y)$.

Comment: So far, so good. With these probabilities you apply the Bayes theorem. What was your calculation?

Comment: Because $P(X \cap Y) = p(2p(1-p)+p^{2})$ and $P(Y)=p$, so $P(X|Y) = 2p(1-p)+p^{2}.$

Comment: I have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(X) = \sum_{k=2}^{3}{3 \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{3-k}$$

This is equivalent to your answer. Please clarify the second question as it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The OP has already the right result.

Comment: @callculus42 yes I know, but you're not supposed to answer in the comments I believe

Comment: I think for confirmations comments are sufficient. It is also a good test if the OP is really interested in an answer.

Comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: I don't think that a confirmation requires an answer.

Comment: @callculus42 but you *are* answering, you are just answering in the comment. Calling it a confirmation doesn't change that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141137/discussion-between-callculus42-and-alborz).

Comment: If the OP needs help that where an answer is necessary I will post one.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches to calculating $p(X|Y).$

It is assumed that $0 < p < 1.$

$\underline{\text{Method 1: Bayes Theorem}}$

$$p(X|Y) = \frac{p(X \cap Y)}{p(Y)}.$$

One way of calculating $p(X \cap Y)$ is by manually examining the mutually exclusive cases:

- All three buy pen : 
  Probability is $p^3.$
- A,B only buy pen : 
  Probability is $p^2(1-p) = p^2 - p^3.$
- A,C only buy pen : 
  Probability is $p^2(1-p) = p^2 - p^3.$

Therefore,

$$p(X \cap Y) = 2p^2 - p^3.$$

Therefore,

$$p(X|Y) = \frac{p(X \cap Y)}{p(Y)} = \frac{2p^2 - p^3}{p} = 2p - p^2.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Method 2}}$

Assuming that event $Y$ happens, the only way that event $X$ can fail to happen is if both of the other two people don't buy a pen.

The probability of this **complementary** event is $(1 - p)^2.$

Therefore,

$$p(X|Y) = 1 - \left[ ~(1-p)^2 ~\right] = 2p - p^2.$$

---

In case it is of interest, $P(Y|X)$ can also be calculated using Bayes Theorem.

$$P(Y|X) = \frac{p(X \cap Y)}{p(X)}.$$

As discussed, $p(X) = 3p^2 - 2p^3.$

Therefore,

$$P(Y|X) = \frac{p(X \cap Y)}{p(X)} = \frac{2p^2 - p^3}{3p^2 - 2p^3} = \frac{2 - p}{3 - 2p}.$$